# Extracting complete log statements from python source code

Tags: python, logging, abstract-syntax-tree

Can you please share how can I extract logger statement from python source code.

For instance I have below snippet:

```
import logger
def some_function(some_list):
    #multi-line logger
    logger.info("Inside 
    some function")
    for item in some_list:
        logger.debug("item is {}}.format(item)
```

The output should be:

```
logger.info("Inside some function") #converted to single line 
logger.debug("item is {}}.format(item)
```

I have used the AST module in python which gives me source code lines that has logger variable

```
#tree is a AST parse tree of python source file
for node in ast.walk(tree):
    #previous = node.parent
    try:
        for child in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
            #print("The length of child nodes is {}".format(len(ast.iter_child_nodes(node))))
            if  child.id == "logger":
                print("The start line no is {} and end line no is {}".format(child.lineno,child.end_lineno))
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Below is the output of the AST script:

```
The start line no is 150 and end line no is 150
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

The start line no is 226 and end line no is 226
logger.info

The start line no is 232 and end line no is 232
logger.info

The start line no is 294 and end line no is 294
logger.info

The start line no is 300 and end line no is 300
logger.info

The start line no is 303 and end line no is 303
logger.info
```

As you can see I am not able to retrieve the entire logger source code lines, any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What difficulty did you encounter when you tried to do this?

Comment: The last line of your snipped is not syntactically correct.  Is that on purpose (related to the tag on your question)?

Comment: this is just an example, I am not able to extract the relevant information with help of ASTs, do you know how can I get the entire logger statements from source code ?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`astor` module](https://pypi.org/project/astor/) makes this easy to do:

```
import ast
import astor

class LogPrinter(astor.TreeWalk):
    def pre_Call(self):
        if (isinstance(self.cur_node.func, ast.Attribute) and
            isinstance(self.cur_node.func.value, ast.Name) and
            self.cur_node.func.value.id == "logger"
           ):
            print(astor.to_source(self.cur_node), end="")
```

You'd call it with something like `LogPrinter(ast.parse(some_source_code))`.

It works by looking for any `ast.Call` node in the ast tree and then checking if the call is being made on an attribute of something named `logger`. You could substitute in some other logic if you want, this was just a quick and dirty version that works on your specific example code (if it's syntax errors are fixed):

```
code_text = """import logger
def some_function(some_list):
    #multi-line logger
    logger.info(
        "Inside some function"
    )
    for item in some_list:
        logger.debug("item is {}".format(item))
"""

LogPrinter(ast.parse(code_text))
```

The output is:

```
logger.info('Inside some function')
logger.debug('item is {}'.format(item))
```

Comment: thank you for the code snippet, I learned something new

Comment: Hi, I can ask another question but since this is somewhat related, asking here. I want to walk the nodes in with astor, I read this link : https://github.com/berkerpeksag/astor/blob/master/astor/node_util.py it has iter nodes function, I want to get source code line above the logger node that has just been discovered